# With pyspark how to format a Nested field in a Spark Data frame?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

After reading in Parquet Files using pyspark I would like to format a field. To replace the **doctime** field with a formatted date. The question is really not about the altering of the format but how to get to this field and replace it.

```
root
 |-- Key: struct
 |    |-- subkey: array
 |    |    |-- subkey1: struct
 |    |    |    |-- name: string
 |    |    |    |-- val: struct
 |    |    |    |    |-- text: string
 |-- Data: struct
 |    |-- subdata: array
 |    |    |-- subdata1: struct
 |    |    |    |-- key1: long
 |    |    |    |-- value: struct
 |    |    |    |    |-- numeric: double
 |    |    |    |    |-- string: string
 |    |    |    |-- doctime: long
 |    |    |    |-- tag: integer
 |    |    |    |-- rptime: long
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html#pyspark.sql.Column.withField) + `transform`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
    "Data",
    F.col("Data").withField(
        "subdata",
        F.transform(
            "Data.subdata",
            lambda x: x.withField("rptime", F.from_unixtime(x["rptime"]))
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks but, looks like transform & withfield is avl only in version 3.1.0 and up. Unfortunately I am chained to pyspark 2.4.7. Any solution for lower version?